# Problema em atualizar Objeto pelo formulário - ASPNET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, crud

Bem, eu estou tentando atualizar os model do meu projeto pelo Formulário, porém, o modelo está sempre vindo null, não importa se eu troque um ou todo os itens, não sei o que fazer

Controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EditarPost([FromForm]Tarefa tarefaAtualizada) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                _tarefaRepository.AtualizarTarefa(tarefaAtualizada);
                TempData["SucessoAtualizadaTarefa"] = "Tarefa atualizada com sucesso";
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Tarefas", "Administrador");
        }
```

Formulário:

```
@model UsuarioTarefa

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Registrar tarefa";
    Layout = "_LayoutAdm";

    @if (TempData["ErrorDate"] != null) {
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            @TempData["ErrorDate"]
        </div>
    } else if (TempData["SucessoAddTarefa"] != null) {
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            @TempData["SucessoAddTarefa"]
        </div>
    }
}
<form asp-controller="Tarefa" asp-action="EditarPost" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="titulo-tarefa-register">Titulo tarefa:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo-tarefa-register" asp-for="@Model.Tarefa.TRF_Titulo" placeholder="Titulo">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="descricao-tarefa-register">Descrição tarefa:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descricao-tarefa-register" asp-for="@Model.Tarefa.TRF_Descrição" placeholder="Descrição"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="data-conclusao-register">Data de conclusão:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="data-conclusao-register" asp-for="@Model.Tarefa.TRF_DataConclusao" placeholder="@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="data-conclusao-register">Usuario para tarefa:</label>
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" asp-for="@Model.Tarefa.TRF_USU_Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Usuarios, "USU_Id", "USU_Name"))">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="data-conclusao-register">Prioridade da tarefa:</label>
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" asp-for="@Model.Tarefa.TRF_PRD_Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Prioridades, "PRD_Id", "PRD_Descricao"))">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form-send">Salvar</button>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Objeto tarefa:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TodoManager.Models {
    [Table("Tarefas")]
    public class Tarefa {
        [Key]
        public int TRF_Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "É obrigado informar um titulo para a tarefa")]
        [Display(Name = "Titulo tarefa")]
        public string TRF_Titulo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "É obrigado informar uma descrição a para a tarefa")]
        [Display(Name = "Descrição tarefa")]
        public string TRF_Descrição { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime TRF_DataCriada { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "Data limite")]
        public DateTime TRF_DataFInalizada{ get; set; }//data que a tarefa foi finalizada
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "É obrigado informar uma data para a conclusão da tarefa")]
        [Display(Name = "Data de conclusão")]
        public DateTime TRF_DataConclusao { get; set; }//data limite que a tarefa pode se concluida

        //relacionamentos com outras tabelas
        //Prioriodade
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "É obrigado informar uma prioridade da tarefa")]
        [Display(Name = "Prioridade da tarefa")]
        public int TRF_PRD_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual PrioridadeTarefa PrioridadeTarefa { get; set; }

        //Usuario
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "É obrigado informar um usuario para realizar a tarefa")]
        [Display(Name = "Usuario da tarefa")]
        public int TRF_USU_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

        //Status tarefa
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "É obrigado informar o status da tarefa")]
        [Display(Name = "Status da tarefa")]
        public int TRF_STS_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual StatusTarefa StatusTarefa { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Objeto UsuarioTarefa:

```
using TodoManager.Models;

namespace TodoManager.ViewModel {
    public class UsuarioTarefa {
        public IEnumerable<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PrioridadeTarefa> Prioridades { get; set; }
        public Tarefa Tarefa { get; set; }

        //utlizado para identificar qual pagina de layout aplicar nas pagina de tarefa
        public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Já tentei trocar o formulario, pedir para IDE gerar mas nada muda

Answer (score 0):

A aplicação não está conseguindo fazer o Binding de UsuarioTarefa para Tarefa

Observe o seguinte, voce declarando seu input dessa forma

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Tarefa.TRF_Titulo">
```

O resultado será algo assim

```
<input name="Tarefa.TRF_Titulo">
```

Quando o browser realiza o POST, sua aplicação C# vai tentar fazer essa associação "Tarefa" "TRF_Titulo"

Ou seja, ele está buscando um objeto do tipo Tarefa dentro de Tarefa.
E o seu endpoint não está esperando por isso.

Para que isso funcionasse, seus inputs deveriam ser assim

```
<input name="TRF_Titulo">
```

Solução simples:

Altere o seu endpoint para receber UsuarioTarefa

```
public IActionResult EditarPost([FromForm] UsuarioTarefa usuarioTarefa)
{
    Tarefa tarefaAtualizada = usuarioTarefa.Tarefa;
}
```

Caso voce precise que seu endpoint receba o objeto Tarefa, considere usar [PartialView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-8.0)